# Is earning $4000/month before tax enough to cover common expenses in Indiana, US?

Tags: usa, taxes, salary, costs

I had a job offer and I'm considering relocation, but I don't know how much the taxes are and how expensive it is to live there.

The job is as a visiting researcher for a university, and it would be in West Lafayette, Indiana.

I want to understand how high the expenses can be (transportation, small single flat rent, food) and how this salary compares to the average salaries of new grads in the US.

Comment: "How good is it" is entirely subjective. It depends on industry, personal preference, your job experience, and about a hundred other things. Is there an *objective* question we might be able to answer for you?

Comment: That's true, but i want to know an estimate of the taxes, of the living costs and a comparison with the salary of a new grad working as a visiting researcher in the field of computer science.

Comment: That sounds like at least two questions: 1) What are the tax rates in Indiana, USA, 2) What is the cost of living in Indiana compared to XYZ location.

Comment: I think both of those would be too temporally localized to be useful if asked separately. I attempted an edit here to be somewhat less subjective.

Comment: Where are you from? To what standard are you used to living?

Comment: Students in West Lafayette Indiana do it for less money.  The question is more on whether you will be able to fit your needs into a $2800/month budget.

Comment: Note that if you are a non-resident, you are not liable for income taxes. That means you get to keep the full $4000. Otherwise, if you pay taxes, be sure to take that into account.

Comment: @einnocent Wouldn't anyone on a temporary visa (such as probably J-1 in this case) be a temporary resident and pay income taxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some tools you can use to compare the numbers with your expectations and goals:

You can

- check the cost of living [here](http://www.areavibes.com/west+lafayette-in/cost-of-living/), and
- calculate the expected tax deductions [here](http://www.paycheckcity.com/covaliant/netpayHRatescalculator.asp).

In case those links go down, the searches I did for those were "west lafayette cost of living" and "indiana tax deductions", respectively. There are likely other comparable websites that provide similar services.

You can also learn more about the city in general at its website: http://www.westlafayette.in.gov/.

Comment: Thanks for the useful websites you provided. Anyway I would need more a first-hand experience of somebody living there or having a similar work position.

Comment: http://www.purdue.edu would be a lot better.